# Passing an std::pair reference taken from an std::map to a function that accepts an std::pair refererence

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

EDIT: The answer to the first question is to use std::pair. Any ideas about the second one (marked as 'bonus question')?

With the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

void foo(std::pair<int, int>& p)  // EDIT: it needs to be non-const
{}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> p{1,2};
    foo(p);
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{{1,2}};
    for (auto& element : v)
    {
        foo(element);  // works fine
    }

    std::map<int, int> m{std::make_pair(1,2)};
    //std::map<int, int> m2{{1,2}};
    for (auto& element : m)  // the problematic loop
    {
        foo(element);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following message with m in the latter for loop:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::pair&' from
>   expression of type 'std::pair'

and the following with m2 in that place:

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'std::pair&' from an rvalue of type 'std::pair'

Why is that?

**Bonus question:**
I find it very peculiar that when the initialization of m2 is not commented out and the for loop stays untouched (there's still m in it and m2 is never used) the error message changes from

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::pair&' from
>   expression of type 'std::pair'

to

> error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'std::pair&' from an rvalue of type 'std::pair'

I'd love to know your thoughts about it. I tested this code with onlinegdb.com

Comment: You didn't quote the errors **verbatim**. If you had, there would have been a mention of `std::pair<const int, int>` and `std::pair<int, int>`. Unrelated types.

Comment: I did, it really only says what I quoted

Comment: Then allow me to recommend compilers with more complete error messages. [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02d153678461d39c) and [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09f429639537f1ad) give much better diagnostics.

Comment: The informative error message in my answer came from GCC 6.3 via [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Lm8jiZ). GDB online seems to be using the relatively elderly GCC 5.4.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map),

```
map::value_type = std::pair<const Key, T>
```

meaning

```
map<int,int>::value_type = pair<const int, int>
```

So the compiler can implicitly convert your element of type `pair<const int,int>&` to a temporary (rvalue) of type `pair<int,int>`, but this can't be passed by non-const ref to the function.

Either change the argument type to `pair<const int,int>`, or take it by value.

---

For reference, gcc 6.3 provided this very informative error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:21:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::pair<int, int>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::pair<int, int>’
         foo(element);
             ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/map:60,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:272:19: note:   after user-defined conversion: constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&) [with _U1 = const int; _U2 = int; typename std::enable_if<(std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<_T1, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<_T2, _U2>::value)), _T1, _T2>::_ConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<_T1, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<_T2, _U2>::value)), _T1, _T2>::_ImplicitlyConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type <anonymous> = 1u; _T1 = int; _T2 = int]
         constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
                   ^~~~
prog.cpp:4:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(std::pair<int, int>&)’
 void foo(std::pair<int, int>& p)
```

Note particularly the strong clue about *after user-defined conversion*...

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. Do you also know the answer to the second question?

Comment: If you see the error I pasted above, it was _always_ `invalid initialization of non-const reference ...` for me. I don't have a copy of GCC 5.4.1 handy to figure out why that one does something different, but it's not obvious.

Answer (score 6):

[The container makes the key `const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (this applies to all associative containers):

> ```
> value_type    std::pair<const Key, T>
> ```

So it should be `void foo(std::pair<int const, int>& p)`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not allowed to modify the keys of the map, hence this works:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

// foo can modify the first value of the pair
void foo(std::pair<int, int>& p)
{}
// fooConstFirst cannot modify the first value of the pair
void fooConstFirst(std::pair<const int, int>& p)
{}

int main()
{
  std::pair<int, int> p{1,2};
  foo(p);
  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v{{1,2}};
  for (auto& element : v)
  {
    foo(element);
  }

  std::map<int, int> m{std::make_pair(1,2)};
  for (auto& element : m)
  {
    fooConstFirst(element);
  }

  return 0;
}
```