# how to Insert a key value pair into a map using implicit converter of a arbitrary data struct?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct keyValue
 {
    int key{0};
    int value {0};

    operator std::pair<int, int>()
    {
        return {key, value};
    }
 };

 void foo(const std::pair<int, int>& pa)
 {
    std::cout << pa.first << std::endl;
    std::cout << pa.second<< std::endl;
 }

 int main ()
 {
    keyValue kv {1,10};
    std::map <int, int> map{};
    foo(kv);
   // map.insert(kv);
    return 0;
 }
```

The struct has an implicit conversion operator to std::pair,
The implicit converter seems to work fine when calling the function for example.
But as soon as I try to call insert or emplace interfaces of the map I get the compilation
error of finding no matching function. Could any one please point out the problem and if it is possible to insert to the map using custom implicit convertor operator at all.
[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ooaW6bzx5)

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: The error message is *"no known conversion for argument 1 from 'keyValue' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::pair<const int, int>&}'"*, because the map stores `pair<const int, int>`. The conversion operator doesn't match that.

Comment: The value_type has key as `const int`. See the answers in the dupe that should tell your the problem and how to solve it: [Passing an std::pair reference taken from an std::map to a function that accepts an std::pair refererence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285629/passing-an-stdpair-reference-taken-from-an-stdmap-to-a-function-that-accepts)

Comment: The question you are mentioning is not mentioning anything about implicit conversion operator. Even if the problem is the same thing. Honestly saying, I do not see any way that some one who is searching for my problem can find his answer from that question. Two different problems the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in `std::map` are `const`, elements of `std::map<int,int>` are `std::pair<const int,int>`.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
struct keyValue
 {
    int key{0};
    int value {0};

    operator std::pair<const int, int>()
    {
        return {key, value};
    }
 };


 int main ()
 {
    keyValue kv {1,10};
    std::map <int, int> map{};
    map.insert(kv);
 }
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EGYK11G3b).

However, implicit conversions are strongly discouraged. You pay the price for a convenient `map.insert(kv)` instead of a `map.insert(kv.get_key_value_pair())` back double and triple for confusing bugs caused by the conversion.

Comment: could you please mention some of the problems (aka bugs) that could rise? In my real case the type (struct) is private to the class that uses the struct.